# Argument "sd" for airflow cli command "trigger_dag" seems to be ignored

Tags: airflow

I'm working with Apache Airflow v1.10.3. When trying to trigger a dag through command line using the command *trigger_dag*, my argument *-sd* seems to be ignored and the default value from the configuration file is being used.

I'm using:

```
airflow trigger_dag -sd "/home/my/custom/dag/folder/dag/" my_test_1
```

Where my_test_1 is the name of the dag.

Before returning the error *airflow.exceptions.DagNotFound: Dag id my_test_1 not found*, it prints:

```
[2019-07-16 14:40:45,956] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-07-16 14:40:46,261] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/tfx/airflow/dags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tfx/.local/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/tfx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tfx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 233, in trigger_dag
    execution_date=args.exec_date)
  File "/home/tfx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/client/local_client.py", line 33, in trigger_dag
    execution_date=execution_date)
  File "/home/tfx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py", line 101, in trigger_dag
    replace_microseconds=replace_microseconds,
  File "/home/tfx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py", line 38, in _trigger_dag
    raise DagNotFound("Dag id {} not found".format(dag_id))
airflow.exceptions.DagNotFound: Dag id my_test_1 not found
```

Note that it says *Filling up the DagBag from **/home/tfx/airflow/dags***, - this is the default dags folder, not the one passed through command line.

Anyone experiencing the same issue?

Cheers

Comment: After filling the dag bag, airflow is trying to find dag id `my_test_1` but it looks like there is no dag with that id.